# Any way to provide Eclipse auto error-discovery feature in Vim/Emacs?

Tags: java, vim, emacs, autocomplete

I know that Vim/Emacs offers some enticing mouse-free capabilities for typing out programs. I have tried both and I love these facilities. But when coding Java, especially when using the libraries extensively, the auto-complete and error-highlighting features of Eclipse are too useful to be set aside. 
                                                                                                                 Is there a way to combine the best of both worlds?

Answer (score 3):

maybe something like this: [Eclim](http://eclim.org/) ?

Comment: sweet! I'll have to check that out myself.

Answer (score 3):

[Vim JDE](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1213) (script) does this for vi, [Eclim](http://eclim.org/) tries to make vi do everything Eclipse does in that sense, but also requires you to run Eclipse in headless mode while you're using vi.

For Emacs, you can try [JDEE](http://jdee.sourceforge.net/).

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to go the other way, and put Emacs/VIM into Eclipse.

in Vim you have `:make` and `:cn` with `:cN` to go through compiler errors/warnings, but its not real time with auto spelling fixes like Eclipse.